# How to Return a "COMMENT" set to a "TABLE"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL-Workbench you're able to see comments that are set to tables (see image below), but I've been unable to find a way to pull that information via SQL Query. If you can write the COMMENT value, you should be able to read it as well, right?

I've searched through documentation for hours, but I've only been able to find different ways of writing.

[image: Example of Comment Set to Table]

Comment: Look in the mysql system tables.  It is in there somewhere, but I don't have a d/b instance handy to tell you where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_comment 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema='my_database' 
    AND table_name='my_table';
```

Full documentation on what is available through the information_schema is found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm!